# Vertical scroll bar on canvas in J2ME

Tags: canvas, scrollbar

I want to draw a vertical scrollbar on the canvas in J2ME.

I'm going to develop the application in J2ME, but how can I add a vertical scrollbar on the canvas in J2ME?

So I can put lots of data on the canvas...

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you calculate the position and then redraw the canvas.